# Uncaught TypeError: $translate is not a function

Tags: angular-translate

This is my code: 
`$translate('singlePointHistory.B').then(function(paragraph{overcrowdedDetail.personNum = paragraph;});`

It gives the following error::

> Uncaught TypeError: $translate is not a function

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a bracket after `paragraph` . So it would be

```
function(paragraph) {
vercrowdedDetail.personNum = paragraph;
});
```

Also, I would try using `$translate.instant(key);`

Make sure you have injected $translate to your controller.